# Prevent activity from being destroyed. youtube player-like behaviour

Tags: android

I've implemented a player activity but I can't make it work like youtube one. The problem is that when I hit display shutdown button, which is usually on the right side of a device, the whole activity gets recreated. Youtube player somehow prevents this behaviour - I bet this is something basic. Could you tell what should I write in my manifest ? :)

Thanks.

Comment: what code are you interested in? Just check out youtube's application: start playing a video, then push display off button and turn it on - video resumes playing instantly - I don't feel like it gets recreated. However mine does get.